# Laravel sort collection and then by key

Tags: php, laravel

I am making raking system for my users and here's what I have so far:

Get all users and sort them by points - it works fine.

```
$users = User::all();
$users = $users->sortByDesc(function($item){
    return $item->points()->sum('amount');
});
```

Find your position in ranking - it works fine

```
$position = 0;
foreach($users as $user){
    if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id) break;
    $position++;
}
```

Get myself and users above/under me - it doesn't work. I get random users. It looks like the collection is not sorted anymore.

```
$myRank = new Collection();
if($position > 9){
    $myRank->add($users->get($position-1));
    $myRank->add($users->get($position));
    $myRank->add($users->get($position+1));
    return view('rank.show', ['topTen' => $users->take(15), 'myRank' => $myRank]);
}
```

Please help me with this one or give some hint on another approach(light weight for many records)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think the problem is this:

When you call `User::all()` you get something like this:

```
0 => points: 10
1 => points: 50
2 => points: 30
3 => points: 70
4 => points: 20
```

Then you use the sortBy function, which reorder the collection, but does not reset the keys. So you end up with something like this:

```
3 => points: 70
1 => points: 50
2 => points: 30
4 => points: 20
0 => points: 10
```

So using position -1, position, and position +1 makes no sense here.

What you can do is using the values() function, which will reset the keys of you collection:

```
0 => points: 70
1 => points: 50
2 => points: 30
3 => points: 20
4 => points: 10
```

So I think the following code would work.

```
$users = User::all();
$users = $users->sortByDesc(function($item){
    return $item->points()->sum('amount');
})->values();
```

And then get 3 users from positions - 1 to position + 1:

```
$myRank = $users->splice($position - 1, 3);
```

Comment: I think you can extend the collection class then call ksort on the backing array. Very dirty hack though

Answer (score 16):

To sort a collection by key, you can sort the backing array by key then recreate the collection again.

```
 $c = collect(['a' => 1, 'c' => 67, 'b' => 2]);
 $items = $c->all();
 ksort($items);

 $c = collect($items);
```

Or you can use a macro to get access to the backing array.

```
 Collection::macro('ksort', function(){
    //macros callbacks are bound to collection so we can safely access
    // protected Collection::items
    ksort($this->items);
    
    return $this;
    //to return a new instance
    //return collect($this->items);
 });
```

The last solution could be very useful if you are going to need to sort collections by key in many places in your code base

Comment: @zarcel whilst it appears in google, this isn't just for your benefit.

Comment: I agree, even if the question isn't relevant to the asker anymore, someone else might find the answers useful. In addition, in two years new solutions might pop up.

Comment: you missed `return $this;` after `ksort($this->items);` in the macro. =)

Comment: @ArashMoosapour returning the instance is not mandatory because ksort takes a reference to the original array

Comment: @peter but when i using ksort on collection it returns null

Comment: @ArashMoosapour I've made the change to return the collection instance. "....... sing ksort on collection it returns null ". You  weren't supposed to assign the return value to a variable.Simply call ksort

Answer (score 2):

For any sorting `array` by `key`, I would suggest native PHP `function` [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the sort collection method:

```
$c = collect(['a' => 1, 'c' => 67, 'b' => 2]);
$c->sort();
```